# I am getting an error httpBasic(withDefaults()) is undefined for the type ServerHttpSecurity.AuthorizeExchangeSpec

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I am working on Spring security for Webflux. When I try to set withDefaults() which is imported from org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults, it is throwing the error

> The method httpBasic(withDefaults()) is undefined for the type
> ServerHttpSecurity.AuthorizeExchangeSpec

. Here is the code that I have built till now. I am trying to build this class from Spring Security examples. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableReactiveMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.MapReactiveUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.header.XFrameOptionsServerHttpHeadersWriter;

@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public MapReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        UserDetails admin = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER","ADMIN")
                .build();
        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user, admin);
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .headers()
                .frameOptions().mode(XFrameOptionsServerHttpHeadersWriter.Mode.SAMEORIGIN);
        http
            .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .httpBasic(withDefaults())
            .formLogin();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try inserting an `and` statement to end the previous statement and start a new.

```
.authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic(withDefaults())
```